# Salt Random Number Based on Timestamp and Phone Number

Tags: java

I'm using the below to generate a random 8 digit numeric code but I would like to secure it by using some user data as a simple script can eventually figure out.  Any ideas on how to salt this value based on unix timestamp and/or phone number (minus the dashes)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateRandomPassword());
    }

    public static String generateRandomPassword() {
        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        int CODE_LENGTH = 8;
        final String letters = "0123456789";

        String pw = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < CODE_LENGTH; i++) {
            int index = (int) (random.nextDouble() * letters.length());
            pw += letters.substring(index, index + 1);
        }
        return pw;
    }
```

Comment: A securerandom uses the best random from the machine available, by adding stuff in like the users phone number, it actually becomes easier for the attacker to crack the output password. The best way to secure your password is adding more variety of output characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Salt is used when storing a hashed version of a password. Like this:

No salt: Password -> hash function => hashed password (possible to retrieve user password)

With Salt: Salt + Password -> hash function => hashed password (not possible to retrieve password unless you also know the salt)

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add phonenumber or timestamp as a Seed to the random number generator, to ensure near true randomness. The SecureRandom constructor returns an unseeded generator. Call the setSeed() method to provide a seed. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phone = "1234567890";
    long seed = Long.valueOf(phone) * 1000 + System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000L;
    System.out.println(generateRandomPassword(seed));
}

public static String generateRandomPassword(long seed) {
    Random random = new SecureRandom();
    random.setSeed(seed);
    int CODE_LENGTH = 8; // Make this static

    Long randomLong = random.nextLong();
    String pw =  Long.toString(randomLong).substring(1, CODE_LENGTH+1); // 
    return pw ; 

    //simplified 
    //return Long.toString(random.nextLong()).substring(1, CODE_LENGTH+1);
}
```

Comment: can you epxlain whats going for the line below?    long seed = Long.valueOf(phone) * 1000 + System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000L;

Comment: Long.valueOf(phone) * 1000: Converts phonenumber from string to a numeric dataType (long), and adds 000 in the end.
System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000L: Gets the current timestamp in milliseconds. But as the first part of this changes slowly (year, date, hour etc), I removed everything except the last 3 digits with the % 1000 operation. This gives a random seed consisting of phonenumber, and the milliseconds.

Comment: This can only give 1000 different seeds for that user, and there is a possibility for duplicate passwords generated. I guess you should use more than just the milliseconds when creating the seed. Maybe it is better to simplify like this:
long seed = Long.valueOf(phone) + System.currentTimeMillis();